# move_uploaded_file in php not working on heroku

Tags: cakephp, heroku

I am uploading images using move_uploaded_file function in php code, but it does not saving the images in a images folder of my app on heroku.

following is the code:
if(move_uploaded_file($bannerfile['tmp_name'],$bannerfilepath)){
...
}

filename and path are correct but images are not saving.

Comment: Can you show us how you are moving the file?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is to check your folder permission, assign a proper permission to the folder which you want the image to be uploaded, (read + write permission).

If it fails, tries to debug your data and make sure the data is correct.

And also, what is the max file size and post_max_size in your php.ini? If the file is bigger, then PHP will stop this and the data will be empty.